# ImageMagick: How can I cut out round from image?

Tags: imagemagick, im4java

I'm trying to make a round avatar out of some image. How can I cut out round from image using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways, but the simplest is probably the undocumented "-vignette" option:

```
magick CLg93.jpg -vignette 1x1 kim_vignette.jpg
```

yields

[image]

You can deal with non-square images by applying an "offset" to the vignette geometry, for example:

`-vignette 1x1+0+50`

if the input image is a portrait that is 100 pixels taller than it is wide.

Comment: I'd probably just crop or resize the input image to create a square image to work with, but in fact the `-vignette` geometry parameter can deal with it -- see the added information about that above.